# What's the syntax for multiple dependency injection using Spring and Scala?

Tags: spring, scala, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm creating a new application using Akka, Scala and Spring. However all the examples I found online show a single dependency being injected. Since the syntax is different from Java, could anyone tell me what'd it look like with multiple DI?

[Spring 4 MVC with Scala](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/spring-4-mvc-scala)

[akka-scala-spring](http://github.com/bijukunjummen/akka-scala-spring)

[Converting a Java Spring application to Scala](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/converting-java-spring-to-scala/)

Example of single DI:

`class HelloWorldController @Autowired() (nameService: Name) {`

Comment: Have you had a look at this SO question: [spring/scala: Possible to autowire bean dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336368/spring-scala-possible-to-autowire-bean-dependencies) ?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin I just did. How's it relevant to what I'm asking? It has no mention of multiple `@Autowired` annotations.

Comment: Sorry, I have picked the wrong link :( Try this one [How to use Spring Autowired (or manually wired) in Scala object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344224/how-to-use-spring-autowired-or-manually-wired-in-scala-object)

Comment: @riccardo.cardin Please read my question again, it's very specific. If you don't understand, don't answer but stop posting useless links.

Comment: Ok, it is possibile that I do not understand your question, but if you have look at link I've posted you, you will see that you can't use the `@Autowired` directly into the constructor in Scala. You've to declare each entity that you want to be injected inside the body of the class and put the annotation over each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by simply adding parameters to the autowired argument list:

```
class HelloWorldController @Autowired() (service1: Foo, service2: Bar)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't used Spring in Scala yet, but if `@Autowired` is anything like Google Guice's `@Inject` - and it looks pretty similar - then this should be all you need in your class file.

Comment: You're right, I eventually had a chance to test it out. See [FeignServiceInterpreter.scala](https://github.com/asarkar/feign/blob/master/app/org/abhijitsarkar/feign/service/FeignServiceInterpreter.scala)